# Python Pandas: Reuse stored means correctly to replace nan

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Over some data, I computed means columnwise.

Let's say the data looks like this

```
 A   B   C   ...  Z
0.1 0.2 0.15 ... 0.17
 .   .   .        .
 .   .   .        .
 .   .   .        .
```

I used the mean() function of DataFrame and as result I got

```
A  some_mean_A
B  some_mean_B
...
Z  some_mean_Z
```

For replacing NaN, I use fillna(). It works for the case of computing the mean and using it during the same execution.

But as soon as I save the means in a file and read it to use it in a different .py file, I get rubbish. The reason is the file with the means are not interpreted correctly. In the new dataset, each NaN of the column A should be replaced by some_mean_A. Same for B and the rest till Z. But this is not happening, because by reading the means with read_csv(), I get the following

```
0   1
A  some_mean_A
B  some_mean_B
...
Z  some_mean_Z
```

When I use this with fillna(), I do not get the expected result.

So, I hope you are understanding my problem. Do you know how to solve this problem?

EDIT 1.0:

This is how I compute and store the means:

```
df_mean = df.mean()
df.fillna(df_mean, inplace=True)  // df is the dataframe for dataset where it works
df_mean.to_csv('mean.csv')
```

This is how I read the means:

```
df_mean = pd.read_csv('mean.csv', header=None)
```

Comment: Can you include how you save and load the means vector? It is probably an index issue.

Comment: I added the saving and reading of the mean vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.mean()` returns a Series. In that Series, values are the means of columns and the indices are the column names. It is a one-dimensional structure. However, if you read that file using `pd.read_csv`'s default parameters, it will read it as a DataFrame: one column for the column names, and another column for the means. To get the same data structure, you need to specify the index and pass `squeeze=True`. This way, pandas will read it into a Series:

```
df_mean = pd.read_csv('mean.csv', header=None, index_col=0, squeeze=True)
```

would give you the same Series for the mean vector. You can add `rename_axis(None)` at the end to get rid of the index name (I think this requires pandas 0.18.0):

```
df_mean = pd.read_csv('mean.csv', header=None, index_col=0).squeeze().rename_axis(None)
```

Comment: What exactly is squeeze doing?

Comment: @tumbler It converts a one-column DataFrame to a Series. It is not mandatory to do that. You can also work on the DataFrame by selecting that single column but this provides you the same data structure you had in the beginning.

Comment: So squeeze only works for one 1D DataFrame like here after saying the first column should be interpreted as index?

Comment: @tumbler Yes, if you have more than one column you cannot convert that into a Series.